# Assigned to project but have nothing to do?

Tags: new-job, careers

I was delighted to be staffed in a project. But after my 4th week on the project, I've noticed that the project manager ignores me.

He didn't even introduce me to the different members of the team, nor do I know my perimeter.

I thought it was strange, but hoped that things would get better in a few days, next week or the week after.

To my surprise, I met someone today who himself was staffed this week, and in the middle of the conversation, He mentioned someone's name. It was the name of the guy I replaced. He told me the guy I replaced was sleeping on the desk, because he wasn't doing anything.

I am worried because this guy was staffed four months before my coming and resigned, and now, they chose me to replace him.

Will I meet the same fate as the guy my position before me?

Comment: Communication, man! Communicate with the manager! Easily 3/4 of all workplace troubles are lack of communication.

Comment: You fret a lot about your job - i could not get a clear picture about your situation from your other questions - could you include a clear timeline (Internshiip-Employment-Staffing-...)? – also, please alter the question to something answerable -'Will i meet the same fate?' is not answerable without a crystal ball.

Answer (score 4):

> Was I chosen to get bored and follow him and resign?

Do they have a reason to want you to resign? Did you show incompetence in your work at the company so far? Are you hated (for a valid reason or despite lack of it)?

Recruitment is an expensive process for companies and if they don't have a reason to want you out, they probably don't.

If you work in consulting, it might be that your company is pursuing an unethical but common strategy among consultancies - they tried to sell the client as many "resources" as possible and the client wasn't smart enough to understand your role isn't needed. So the client is paying for your "work", although you aren't doing anything. Your company is earning money and the only problem is you are bored. As I say, it's unethical, but not uncommon.

I've worked on large projects, where 20% of our consultants were such "placeholders". Their role was to pretend that they worked and were needed. The company was happy as they had 100% chargeability. Some of them even got promoted because of these roles! Of course, when you pretend to be working you can't snore or be missing since that's something the client would notice, even if they aren't the brightest. Which explains why your predecessor was fired.

Talk to your manager. Ask them whether they are happy with your performance. Ask them for more work. If they give a strange, avoidant explanation for your request for more work, it's probably because the explanation above (unethical behavior towards the client) is correct.

If the conversation doesn't bring anything you need to decide whether it makes sense for you to stay in a company in which you don't learn anything and basically waste time.

Comment: " in which you don't learn anything ".... well, paid downtime is a good time to improve potentially useful skills.  E.g. look vlookup and index in excel,  read up on new programming languages, catch up on incoterms, ... whatever might be relevant for your next real job.

Comment: @Hennes, you learn most by doing. Reading about something new while pretending to work doesn't tend to be very productive.